# Which hero do you need to level "x" amount of times before "ascend" option pops up?

Tags: clicker-heroes

I have about 5500 combined hero levels and absolutely nowhere can I find an "ascension" button. It just says I have two hero souls waiting upon ascending.

This is on Xbox One.

Comment: i promise its not. other question and the answer subsequantly provided were incredibly unclear

Comment: Fine then.., I'll just make a comment on one of the other posts so for users like myself who find the questions unclear and unsubstantiated, may find them to be clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to ascend you will need the hero [Amenhotep](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Amenhotep) leveled to 150.  If I remember correctly he has a skill that you click on to ascend that is unlocked at 150.